# Looping through instances for django

Tags: python, django

models.py

```
    from django.db import models
from collections import Counter
from django.db.models import Count
from itertools import groupby
Gender = (
    ('Male', 'MALE'),
    ('Female', 'FEMALE'),
)

Diseases = (
    ('Cholera', 'CHOLERA'),
    ('HIV', 'HIV'),
    ('Malaria', 'MALARIA'),
    ('Typhoid', 'TYPHOID'),
    ('Measles', 'MEASLES'),
)


class MyModel(models.Model):
    Gender = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=Gender, default='MALE')
    Diseases = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=Diseases, default='MALARIA')
    vote = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
            r=0
            return u'%s %s' % (self.Gender, self.Diseases)
```

Now this returns this in the admin django panel

```
Male Measles
Male Measles
Male Cholera
Female Cholera
Female Typhoid
Female Typhoid
```

But I want to group it so it looks something like this:

```
Male malaria 2
Male Measles 2
Female Typhoid 3
```

in this admin panel instead of listing all of it like it does now

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you read through django's documentation for creating models, making queries to database through django's python shell and about relationships between databases/relationship fields.

[Documentation on making queries to the database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/)

[Documentation on database relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#module-django.db.models.fields.related)

[Documentation on models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/)

As of your problem, I would create 2 models: Person, Disease

```
class Person(models.Model):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
    )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices = GENDER_CHOICES)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Then a model of disease, and since people have diseases and not the other way around, I would give the disease model a foreign key of person

```
class Disease(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    DISEASE_CHOICES = (
        ('CHOLERA', 'Cholera'),
        ('HIV', 'HIV'),
        ('MALARIA', 'Malaria'),
        ('TYPHOID', 'Typhoid'),
        ('MEASLES', 'Measles'),
    )
    disease = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=DISEASE_CHOICES)
```

After you create instances for those models you can call this in python shell and get results you are looking for:

```
for i in Disease.objects.all():
    if i.person.gender == 'M':
         if i.disease in males:
             males[i.disease] += 1
         else:
             males.update({i.disease:1})
     elif i.person.gender == 'F':
         if i.disease in females:
             females[i.disease] += 1
         else:
             females.update({i.disease:1})
```

In my test case the output was:

```
>>> males
{'HIV': 2, 'MALARIA': 2, 'TYPHOID': 2}
>>> females
{'HIV': 2}
```

NOTE: You should define empty dicts `males` and `females` before executing the loop above.

You can run this after to get the results like you want them to be:

```
for k in males:
    'Males ' + k + ' ' + str(males[k])
```

Results in my case:

```
'Males HIV 2'
'Males MALARIA 2'
'Males TYPHOID 2'
```

It's up to you to remake this into a method.

Comment: But its not incrementing.I need count in there also

Comment: @DGIDGI I updated the answer, it should work just fine if you use this code, you can remake it into a method in models.py and just call it whenever you need fresh information.